# Java how to read stdin?

Tags: java, input

I need to read the input that is piped to my java program. This is a simple task but I couldn't find it on the net.

This is what I tried:

```
private static String getInput() throws IOException {
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
  BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
  String line;
  while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    sb.append(line);
  }

  return sb.toString();
}
```

First of all, is there a simpler way to do it (in java 11, or maybe with a library)? It seems like a lot of lines for such a simple task.

And mostly, it seems that it doesn't work if there is no piped input, it hangs, when I just want it to return null for example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since Java 8, you can read all lines into a `Stream<String>`:

```
private static String getInput() {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    return reader.lines().collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));
}
```

If you want to keep the newlines, you can use an overload for `Collectors.joining()`, like `Collectors.joining("\n")`

The problem with interactive input is: You may not know if there is an other line coming. So you have to signal end-of-file using your operating system input.
On windows this is the sequence <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>, while on Linux it's <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>

Comment: As I said in my comment to the other answer, I need to be able to read std input (such as echo "foobar" | java -jar my.jar), not user input. So your answer doesn't apply, does it ?

Comment: It does. It reads all input from the standard input. And there is a difference between "empty" and "not yet filled". As I described in my answer, you have to signal the end of that.

Comment: As a test, I run it with an empty file as input `touch empty; java Test < empty`, and it did read - 0 characters.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand your answer then. Why would I need to send a signal ? If I type `echo hi |  sed 's/hi/ho/'` in bash, it returns 'ho' and sed does not need to be signaled when the input has been read. I just want a program that reads from its piped input, without any user interaction.

Comment: You don't need the signal if you pipe something in. But if you have user input, you have to end it. As you probably have to do with sed too.

Comment: But if I don't pipe something in, then I want that function to return 'null'. In my usecase I will never ask the user to input it by hand. And all I want is to retrieve the stdin, so if there's no stdin, then just return null. Can you please update your code to reflect this ?

Comment: If you don't redirect stdin, then stdin comes from the console. There is no reliable way to tell if stdin is a file, a socket, console or something else.

Comment: Wow this is amazingly sad, I didn't know that. When you say 'there is no reliable way', then are there 'unreliable ways' ? Is it at least possible to "detect it", in order to write a message such as 'no input from in stdin, please type in string to give as input to the program' ?

Comment: You can check `System.in.available()`, but that's about it.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and prompt replies sir. I marked your answer as my accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can not read `null` from `System.in` but you can terminate the input on an empty string and then return `null` if the length of the input is `0`.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(getInput());
    }

    private static String getInput() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        for (String line = scanner.nextLine(); !line.isEmpty(); line = scanner.nextLine()) {
            sb.append(line).append(System.lineSeparator());
        }
        return sb.length() == 0 ? null : sb.toString();
    }
}
```

**A sample run:**

```
Hello
World
How are you?

Hello
World
How are you?
```

**Another sample run:**

```
null
```

Comment: Maybe my question wasn't very clear. I just want everything from the stdin to be in my variable, as is. So first of all, it seems that I forgot to add a newline and it should be sb.append(line).append("\n") instead. And as for the second part of my question, if there's nothing in the stdin, I want getInput() to return null (in other words, `echo "" | java -jar my.jar` and `java -jar my.jar` should produce an empty string in the first case and a null string in the second). Which doesn't seem to be the case here.

Comment: There also seems to be another confusion: the program does not read user input. It needs to read what was piped to it by a previous program. So I don't think scanner works.

Comment: @HagridV - Based on your update, I've updated my answer to include line separator. I've also updated my answer to return `null` as per your requirement. Feel free to comment in case of any further doubt/issue.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It does not seem to work when the input is empty though, does it ? As in, if I type java -jar my.jar, it just hangs.

Comment: Thanks to the other answer, I understood better why it was hanging. So your answer is also correct, I added +1 to it. Thank you.